# Google Maps APIv2 Issue

Tags: android, api, google-maps

I have this error in android console:

```
08-25 21:27:10.446  11891-11924/com.example.mamnay.map D/Volley﹕ [555] a.a: HTTP response for request=<[ ] https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap/api 0x99e6744e NORMAL 2> [lifetime=5900], [size=231188], [rc=200], [retryCount=0]
08-25 21:27:10.456  11891-11891/com.example.mamnay.map D/Volley﹕ [1] p.b: 5910 ms: [ ] https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap/api 0x99e6744e NORMAL 2
08-25 21:27:10.626  11891-11942/com.example.mamnay.map E/PGA﹕ [11942] Connection closed by host (err = 104), possibly due to exception: App cannot continue with current context. Exiting.
08-25 21:27:10.626  11891-11942/com.example.mamnay.map A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000123 (code=1), thread 11942 (Thread-570)
08-25 21:27:10.636  11891-11932/com.example.mamnay.map D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1015K, 20% free 4913K/6116K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
```

Comment: It seems your connection was rejected by host. You should re-check your `keys and credentials`.

Comment: thanks for your response

Comment: i'm new in android and i don't know how to do this

Comment: What are you going to approach?

Comment: i create a new project in android studio with option google map (that is offered in android studio) and android studio extract my SHA1+my package plus link with this infos. that you generate an android api key for your project
and finally i copied this key in my projet (just like some tutoriel that i follow in net) and i build my projet
thanks for response

Comment: and i'm sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: for information i run my project directly in bluestack may be is the source of my problem

Comment: Take look at [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ADb5bNOFHE&list=WL&index=8) video, I think it should help you out.

Comment: ok thanks brother :)

Comment: No problem, I posted a answer, you can accept if you feel that I helped you.

Comment: thanks :) i follow the same steps that in videos but the problem is not solved
when i begin watching the video i feel that he can help me because first the video proprietaire it is a professional in android and second i never try to proceed with generate a signed apk key and extract sha1 of this signed apk for that i feel that the problem will solve in beginning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we discussed above, please follow the step [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ADb5bNOFHE&list=WL&index=8) video should be really help.

You can get SHA1 by using:

`keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -list -v`

and the password by default is `android`.

[image]

Comment: i have an opinion
in video we proceed by generate unsigned apk by .jks key and this key is for release version and that precede the proper key SHA1 that we use to generate API Key.
but your procedure is to use debug.keystore that is compatible with debug mode
for that when i use your proposition android studio show a error : authentication failed and if i use the correct key SHA-1 (this key that Android Studio show for me is different to the debug.keystore that i use in google console developer)

Comment: it is normal because i generate a signed akp that use file .jks with his proper key SHA-1 and in google console developer i use debug.keystore :)

Comment: Why you call this  `clients4.google.com/glm/mmap/api  `api address, do you just wanna show a map on the phone or something? If so, please check my code [here](https://github.com/jbj88817/GoogleMap-basic-android). And for the map, please follow the official doc [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/signup).

Comment: Also you can follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S-LW0DinKrk) video if you want.

Comment: thanks :) it's not me that call this link but it's generated by code that display map (from first tutorial that you send to me)

Comment: thanks brother :) finaly it's solved thank you very much :)

Comment: How did you solve the 400 error for clients4.google.com/glm/mmap/api? What did you change?